# Question mark in a regular expression: difference between 'Pattern.compile("\"title\":\"(.*?)\"");' and 'Pattern.compile("\"title\":\".*\"");'

Tags: java, regex

I want to know if there is a difference in these two regular expressions:

```
Pattern.compile("\"title\":\"(.*?)\"");
Pattern.compile("\"title\":\".*\"");
```

The part `(.*?)` and `.*` looks like they have the same meaning...

Here I get exactly the same results:

```
        String title = null;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"title\":\"(.*?)\"");
        //Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"title\":\".*\"");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("sdfssdfsdfsdfsdf\"title\":\"Here is the title\"sdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg");
        if (m.find()) {
            title = m.group();
        }
        System.out.println(title);
```

Output:

```
"title":"Here is the title"
```

If I do not use parentheses - I'm still able to find separate groups like that:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"title\":\".*?\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher("sdfssdfsdfsdfsdf\"title\":\"Here is the title\"dfdfgrt\"title\":\"Here is the title\"");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

The output:

```
"title":"Here is the title"
"title":"Here is the title"
```

So - do I really need parentheses here?

Comment: non-greedy , capturing group.

Comment: check with this `"sdfssdfsdfsdfsdf\"title\":\"Here is the title\"\"title\":\"Here is the title\""` input.

Comment: Yes, that's right - result now is twice repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things here:

`()` --> Specifies a *capturing group*. So, if you want to *capture something* and want to refer to it later, you can use `(what you want to capture here)`. Without the braces, you don't capture the data.

`.*` --> is greedy i.e, it tries to grab the entire string and goes one character less and tries to match again.

`.*?` --> is lazy (AKA *reluctant*) i.e, starts from length 0 and tries matching the string and stops at first match.

You could look at [the official documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

Try this code for `matching` without `capturing`

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc(.*?)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("abc");
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        System.out.println("group1: " +  m.group(1));
    }
```

Output:

```
hi
group1:
```

Comment: Somehow I found (EDIT2 above) that in my situation parentheses are not needed.. Am I right?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis - Well, `m.group()` returns the *entire matched String*. Not the captured group. Use parenthesis and try `m.group(1)` and see what happens :P (hint : Don't try this in production code :P)

Comment: Question is answered 100%. But why not in production code (I mean there is a situation)?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis - Be careful to make sure that *there is a group* else `group(1)` will give you error :) . Note that `group()` is same as `group(0)`.  *Actual*  groups start from `1` . Note : `group()` can be used freely .

Comment: But if `m.find()` is `true` - doesn't that mean that group 1 exists (talking about the same regex with parentheses)?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis - No. `find()` tries to do a match and returns on the first match. It doesn't mean that there is a captured group. It means that there is a match. In your *edit-2* change `group()` to `group(1)` and see what I mean :P

Comment: OK, but this group `(.*?)` will always be captured :)? Even there is no symbols.. Also `m.groupCount()` would help think.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis - There are 2 things here. 1. `find()` will return false if what you are looking for is not found in the string. 2. if a match is found then `(.*?)`  will print `""` if nothing has been captured.. Check my edit :)

Comment: At least it will not throw an exception. That is OK, thanks indeed for help!

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis - Remove the *braces* and it will :P.. You are welcome :)